# runtime - What does this "@@:" mean in class_addMethod?

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

Use `class_addMethod` Code:

```
class_addMethod(newClass, @selector(inputAccessoryView), accessoryImp, "@@:");
```

What dose the parameter "@@:" mean in this method?

Doc:

```
/** 
 * Adds a new method to a class with a given name and implementation.
 * 
 * @param cls The class to which to add a method.
 * @param name A selector that specifies the name of the method being added.
 * @param imp A function which is the implementation of the new method. The function must take at least two arguments—self and _cmd.
 * @param types An array of characters that describe the types of the arguments to the method. 
 * 
 * @return YES if the method was added successfully, otherwise NO 
 *  (for example, the class already contains a method implementation with that name).
 *
 * @note class_addMethod will add an override of a superclass's implementation, 
 *  but will not replace an existing implementation in this class. 
 *  To change an existing implementation, use method_setImplementation.
 */
OBJC_EXPORT BOOL class_addMethod(Class cls, SEL name, IMP imp, 
                             const char *types) 
OBJC_AVAILABLE(10.5, 2.0, 9.0, 1.0);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `types` parameter describes the arguments and return type of the
method as described in 
[`class_addMethod`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1418901-class_addmethod?language=objc):

> An array of characters that describe the types of the arguments to the method. For possible values, see [Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide > Type Encodings](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html). Since the function must take at least two arguments— `self` and `_cmd`, the second and third characters must be “@:” (the first character is the return type).

`"@@:"` describes a method with returns an object
(type encoding `@`, in your case: `UIView *`) and takes no arguments apart from the fixed (hidden) arguments `self` (type encoding `@` for object) and `_cmd` (type encoding `:` for selector).

Comment: If `SEL` is `@selector(viewWithObject:)` ,  the `types` will be "@@:@" ?

Comment: @tom: Yes if the method takes an object as argument and returns an object.

Answer (score 1):

You know the method in Objective has the below signature

(return type)(function_name)(id self, SEL cmd, ...)

@@: mean
The first character standing for the return type. @ mean object type (class type)
The second `self` parameter
The third is `SEL`
This function doesn't have the parameter therefore end of with `:`

For example:
"v@:i@"

```
-(void)functionName:(int)arg arg2:(id)arg2;
```

mean

1. v: is the return type with void type
   @: is self and SEL
   i is an integer argument
   @ is an object type argument

You can check it out the Apple document to know futher.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH100